# Parallax scrolling effect not displaying

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my background image to display on my CSS file for my portfolio website. I am pretty sure, my CSS file is completely ignoring my div. parallax area for some reason and I am pretty sure there is a small mistake that I am ignoring. Sorry for the newbie question, but I am new to HTM and I only use it for my portfolio website.

I made the CSS adjustments for parallax and also made sure my parallax stuff in HTML is working but I can't seem to see any changes. I have added some surrounding code to make sure that I am not putting anything in the wrong place.

This is the HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="clearfix">
        <a href="#"><s>Zarif Rahman</s></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/z&r_logo.png" alt="dribble icon"></a>
        </nav>
        <div class ="parallax">
        <header>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
        <p>


   Large text here <a href="mailto:zarifurzarif@gmail.com"> email</a>.
        </p>
        </header>
```

This is the CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
html {
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FEA49F;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.parallax{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: image("images/IMG_5223.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
```

Nothing seems to be displaying despite my efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This background-image image is wrong, correctly is background-image url

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
html {
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FEA49F;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.parallax{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="clearfix">
        <a href="#"><s>Zarif Rahman</s></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/z&r_logo.png" alt="dribble icon"></a>
        </nav>
        <div class ="parallax">
        <header>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
        <p>


   Large text here <a href="mailto:zarifurzarif@gmail.com"> email</a>.
        </p>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image: image("images/IMG_5223.jpg");` is wrong usage. It should be `background-image: url("images/IMG_5223.jpg")` or `background: url("images/IMG_5223.jpg")` .
 Please have a look at [background-image property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)